# Use Objective-C framework in Swift Cocoa framework project

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, frameworks

I am recently writing a Cocoa framework in Swift. However, it uses classes in Microsoft Band SDK. But the Microsoft Band SDK framework is Objective-C framework. After I added the MSBand SDK framework:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//! Project version number for WearableKit.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double WearableKitVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for WearableKit.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char WearableKitVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <WearableKit/PublicHeader.h>

#import <MicrosoftBandKit_iOS/MicrosoftBandKit_iOS.h>
```

I got the error: "include of non-modular header inside framework module"

```
/Users/SharpPug/Documents/Repo/WearableKit/WearableKit/WearableKit.h:19:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'WearableKit'
#import <MicrosoftBandKit_iOS/MicrosoftBandKit_iOS.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'WearableKit'
```